# "Had decided" vs "decided"

Tags: grammar

They say *had* is only when an action was completed (finished or "perfected") at some point in the past before something else happened.

But i recently heard a sentence from *Fault in Our Stars*:

> Hazel says I didn't believe a word.
>   But that's okay.
>
> I knew this was the right thing to do.
>   Funerals, I *had* decided, are not for the dead.
>   They're for the living.

Shouldn't it be *decided*, not *had decided*
as no other event is mentioned there
after or before that?

Comment: The speaker had decided that _before_ the other things in his story happened. So everything the speaker is telling you about what happened (_I knew_) happened after the _I had decided_.

Comment: Hello and welcome to EL&U. I've edited your question to make it clearer. Please feel free to [edit] it further or to roll back the changes.

Comment: Thank you @lawrence? Could you please answer it too?

Comment: Here's a little writeup about the two sites: [What is the difference between ELU and ELL?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3723/142322)

Comment: I have to post the same question on ELL?

Answer (score 3):

The perfect relates a prior eventuality to one occurring at 'reference time' (RT) —the time of the situation you are talking about.

Establishing RT does not require an "event"—it may be established by a "non-event" such as remaining silent or by a state such as knowing or being.

The RT in this case is established before the past perfect is used: *I **did**n't*, *I **knew***. In this context, *I had decided* indicates that the speaker reached the decision that funerals are for the living, not the dead,**before** RT, and that decision gave rise to his knowledge at RT that not speaking was the right thing to do.

Comment: now i kind of got it. But could you please provide me some more examples of this sort. So that i could understand better?

Comment: @user62492 "I ***had written*** (pa·pf) a very short answer, so you ***didn't** (past) understand my original answer." RT is past, your not understanding, and my writing occurred before that and gave rise to your not understanding.

Comment: had occurred before that and gave rise to your not understanding*

Comment: @user62492 Sorry - 'past perfect'.

Comment: DO use comments to [ask for clarification, suggest changes, or offer short-lived information](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). DO NOT use them for minor edits ([edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) instead) answers (post an [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) instead), praise or rebukes ([vote](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) instead), discussion ([chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) instead), or comments on site design or policy (post at [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/) instead).